# Why are smart app banners partially/completely hidden in Safari when I have viewport specified?

Tags: html, ios, responsive-design

I want to add [smart app banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to link to an app in the Apple App Store. It seems to work fine when I don't have a viewport metatag specified. If I have a fully mobile friendly viewport, the smart app banner is hidden completely "behind the address bar" after page load, and if I have a viewport with width 840 specified, the smart app banner is partially hidden by the address bar.

Why is this, and can I make it so that the smart app banner is always completely shown?

### Working, no viewport

The smart app banner is shown correctly. You can scroll to hide it.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=284882215">
```

[Test page](https://gist.githack.com/tgwizard/1d5047f15c038df59fa6/raw/10a7cb12f6537e0866bbb07b9a4bedb93242b39c/smart-app-banner-viewport-none.html)

[image: Correct smart app banner]

### Completely hidden, responsive

The smart app banner is hidden behind the address bar (you can see a blurry blue Facebook logo). You can scroll to hide/show it.

````
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=284882215">```
````

[Test page](https://gist.githack.com/tgwizard/1d5047f15c038df59fa6/raw/617512fe287d73043b15d338f65e19636a27c57b/smart-app-banner-viewport-responsive.html)

[image: Fully hidden smart app banner]

### Partially hidden, viewport width=840

The smart app banner is partially hidden behind the address bar. You can scroll to hide it/show it completely.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=840, user-scalable=yes" />
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=284882215">
```

[Test page](https://gist.githack.com/tgwizard/1d5047f15c038df59fa6/raw/14ba993a10f6b0359298b857e0cdb5b702b3446a/smart-app-banner-viewport-width.html)

[image: Partially hidden smart app banner]

This can only really be tested in Safari on a real iPhone, and it is easiest to do it in Private Mode, as the appearance of the smart app banner changes if you scroll / reload the page.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Please post an answer if you figure it out.

Comment: it's sad that we cannot see how safari injects the banner into the page, then we could debug it better.

Answer (score 5):

Initially force window to scroll top solved the issue for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(-100);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is however quite irritating if you reload the page and want to be on the same position as before.

Answer (score 3):

This issue also affects [universal app link banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

A vanilla javascript solution which worked for us was:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, -100);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">` 
and it would show the smart banner.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work for us. seems like some other part of the page layouting causes issues.